# Can anyone suggest me the effective way to deal with s3 upload fail because of timezone difference issue?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I tried both SDK version V1 and V2. I have application in which I am posting user's photo/video on s3. When the device's timezone is not set to automatic,many times uploading fails because of timezone difference. I am not able to catch this error or exception consistently. `didFailWithError` never get called for timezone difference,I have to catch it in `didCompleteWithResponse`.

I used below code for 1.7.1 SDK.

```
    [AmazonLogger verboseLogging];
    AmazonS3Client *s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:AWS_AccessKey withSecretKey:AWS_SecretKey];
    s3.endpoint=[AmazonEndpoints s3Endpoint:US_EAST_1];

    @try 
    {

        por = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:[aStrAWSPath lastPathComponent] inBucket:aStrFolder];
        por.contentType = aStrType;
        por.data        = aDataToPost;
        por.delegate=self;
        [por setCannedACL:[S3CannedACL publicReadWrite]];
        [s3 putObject:por];
        aWSTotalBytesWritten = 0.0;
    }
    @catch (AmazonServiceException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",exception.description);
    }
    @catch (AmazonClientException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",exception.description);
    }

-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didCompleteWithResponse:(AmazonServiceResponse *)response
{
        if(response.exception==nil)
        {
          //Success
        }
        else
        {
           if([response.exception isKindOfClass:[AmazonServiceException class]])
           {
             AmazonServiceException *aServiceExceptionObj=(AmazonServiceException *)response.exception;
             if([aServiceExceptionObj.errorCode isEqualToString:@"RequestTimeTooSkewed"])
             {
                //Please check your date&time settings.It should be set to automatically.
             }
        }       
}
-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
     NSLog(@"AWSError : %@", error.description);
}
```

In AWSiOSSDKv2,I used below code,

```
AWSServiceConfiguration *aConfigObj=[AWSServiceConfiguration configurationWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:CustomCredentialsProviderObj];
AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [[AWSS3TransferManager alloc] initWithConfiguration:aConfigObj identifier:@"testUplaod"];
AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
uploadRequest.bucket = @"testsdkv2/testsdkv2internal";
uploadRequest.key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg",(int)[[NSDate date]timeIntervalSince1970]];
NSURL *aUrlObj=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"jpg"]];
uploadRequest.body = aUrlObj;
uploadRequest.ACL=AWSS3BucketCannedACLPublicReadWrite;
uploadRequest.contentType=@"image/jpeg";

[[transferManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {


    if (task.error)
    {
        //Not uploaded
    }

    if (task.result)
    {
        // The file uploaded successfully.
    }

    return nil;
}];
```

Comment: The version 1 of the SDK is deprecated, so you should focus on the v2 SDK.

The timezone difference should not cause any issue, but a skewed device clock causes a timestamp too skewed exception in AWS Signature Version 4. The SDK should automatically fix the skewed clock issue. Have you printed out the content of `task.error`? Also, you should enable the verbose logging by calling `[AWSLogger defaultLogger].logLevel = AWSLogLevelVerbose;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by setting "ClockSkew" to the difference between my UTC time and server's UTC time by taking [Managing-Device-Time-with-the-AWS-Mobile-SDKs](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2KKPVXE69XJAO/Managing-Device-Time-with-the-AWS-Mobile-SDKs) in refference.

```
[NSDate aws_setRuntimeClockSkew:aTimeInterval];
```

Answer (score 0):

On the worst of hypothesis, try using `AFNetworking` and set custom header fields, including date. It is also faster. Import the `AFNetworking` library using cocoa pods and upload your files like this:

```
NSString *fileContentTypeStr = //file type string;
NSURL *imageUploadURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image"]];
[data writeToURL:self.imageUploadURL atomically:YES];
AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest *getPreSignedURLRequest = [AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest new];
getPreSignedURLRequest.bucket = //Bucket;
getPreSignedURLRequest.key = //Key Name;
getPreSignedURLRequest.HTTPMethod = AWSHTTPMethodPUT;
getPreSignedURLRequest.expires = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3600];
getPreSignedURLRequest.contentType = fileContentTypeStr;
[[[AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder defaultS3PreSignedURLBuilder] getPreSignedURL:getPreSignedURLRequest]
 continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
     if (task.error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@",task.error);
     } else {
         NSURL *presignedURL = task.result;
         NSMutableURLRequest *URLRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:presignedURL];
         [URLRequest setValue:fileContentTypeStr forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
         //Set your custom header field here
         URLRequest.HTTPMethod = @"PUT";
         URLRequest.HTTPBody = imageData;

         AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
         NSProgress *progress;
         NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:URLRequest progress:&progress completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
             if(error)
             {
                 UIAlertView *b = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"An error ocurred",nil) message: [error userInfo][@"error"] delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Dismiss",nil) otherButtonTitles: nil];
                 [b show];
             }
         }];
         [progress addObserver:self
                    forKeyPath:@"fractionCompleted"
                       options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                       context:NULL];
         [uploadTask resume];
     }
     return nil;
 }];
```

Comment: I tried this code referring [uploading-files-amazon article](http://www.juliusparishy.com/articles/uploading-files-amazon-aws-s3-background-afnetworking-2-0),but no luck. It continue giving me 1001 1003 1005 error codes.

Comment: There's one more conventional solution for this issue to upload files via backend but I don't want to go ahead with that approach.